# Regex match with 3 condition?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I will creating math program .If i wish to solve i need separate to the equation using with regex.
***For example:***

```
     `10x-10y2+100x-100k=100`
```

the format will separate with regex `output: "10x" ,"100x" ,"100k" ,"10y2","100"`

I have already code for that with separate match function

***There are:***

```
           for num[a-z]num : ` /([\-+])?\s*(\d+)?([a-z]?(\d+))/g`
           for num[a-z]    : ` /([\-+])?\s*(\d+)?([a-z]?(\d+))/g`
           fon num         : `/\b[+-]?[\d]+\b/g`
```

I need all this three match function within one regex match function.some one help to combine the code with single regex expression

> Note :i need match function only  not a split beacause i apply that regex expression into parser

Thank You.

Comment: Why would `-10y2` ever be a valid input?

Comment: The first 2 regexes look exactly the same. Remember, you can always just "OR" each regex together: `/([\-+])?\s*(\d+)?([a-z]?(\d+))|\b[+-]?[\d]+\b/g` and it will match the first regex if possible, then the second, and so on.

Comment: @Whothehellisthat a its vaild input

Comment: Oh. I'm familiar with algebra, but I've never seen a use for -10 * y * 2. Maybe that's not how it works. What does that mean if you spell it out?

Comment: i mean `-10y^2` power `2`

Comment: Ah, so we need to handle `^` also? And do you only want each expression ("-10y^2") not every single part ("1", "+", "10y")?

Comment: i want to each expersion

Answer (score 2):

Split on symbols:

```
"10x-10y2+100x-100k=100".split(/[-+=]/);
```

Output:

```
["10x", "10y2", "100x", "100k", "100"]
```

If you need to use `match()` method I suggest same approach:

```
"10x-10y2+100x-100k=100".match(/[^-+=]+/g);
```

Output is the same.

Comment: i need match function not a split because i apply that regex expression into parser

Comment: not like that..match the format only. like `10z` --> `num[a-z]`

Comment: Then you may want to go with two other answers from Daniel and hsz.

Answer (score 1):

[`/(?:0|[1-9]\d*)?(?:[a-z]+)?(?:\^(?:0|[1-9]\d*))?/g`](https://regex101.com/r/yX5gR3/4)

```
// finds:
//        vvv vvvvv vvvv vvvv vvvvv vv vvv       v vvv
          10x-10y^2+100x-100k=100^4+xy+100+100y2+0-1^0
// doesn't find:                           ^^^^^
```

- `(?:0|[1-9]\d*)?` 0, OR 1-9 then zero or more numbers. Optional.
- `(?:[a-z]+)?` Optional one or more lowercase letters.
- `(?:\^[1-9]\d*)?` Optional power.

  - `\^` Literal text.
  - `(?:0|[1-9]\d*)` Zero, OR 1-9 then zero or more numbers.

If I've missed anything let me know and I'll incorporate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 s.match(/\d+([A-Za-z]\d*)?/g)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with following regex:

```
/(\d+[a-z]?\d*)/g
```

[example](https://regex101.com/r/aT7uX1/1)